# Datatables & Wordpress - Calling PHP file From Javascript

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datatables

Basically, I have some code in a my theme folder, in the /js/public.js file.  Im using Datatables, and as per their example, im using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#certificates-table').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "../wp-content/themes/theme1064/includes/_get_certificates.php"
    } );
} );
```

Basically, I've hardcoded the location for SAjaxSource, but I need to use get_template_directory_uri() so its dynamic, or something similar...

Any idea how to do that here in the JS file?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../includes/_get_certificates.php",
        type: "GET",

        success: function(data) {              
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('ERR');
        },
        timeout: function () {
            console.log('ERR');
        }
    });
```

Comment: is this going in the public.js?  if so, how am I using it in conjunction with the datatables javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, I did something really ugly but it works:
`javascript_code() {sUpdateURL : "<?php echo MY_PLUGIN_DIR; ?>UpdateData.php};"`
Maybe there's a better way?